# Increase CloudSearch _score by specific number

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

I am new to AWS cloudsearch, There is relevance score (_score) which is computed automatically based on the search terms occurrences..

My question is that Can I increase my relevance score(_score) by specific amount based on specific key value..

**Example:**

Lets say cloudsearch returns following two documents

```
fields: {
    {
       fullname: "Daniel Wildt",
       active: "T",
       _score: "82"
    }
    {
       fullname: "Robert",
       active: "F",
       _score: "84"
    }
}
```

I want First document (Daniel Wildt) to be higher... It means by **active = T** aws should add something to the score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use a custom `rank` directly because that's only available for sort-enabled numeric fields (int, double, date).

Here are a couple alternative options

- **Sorting**: if you plan to give a lot of weight to the `active` field, it will become dominant enough to be functionally equivalent to the the `sort` operator. That is, you can just add `sort=active desc` to your query to get the T results before F
- **Convert to int**: map T and F to numeric values before submitting your documents to be indexed, eg T=1 F=0, then use these in a custom rank expression to affect the ordering of results `&expr.myrank=_score+active&sort=myrank`
- **Field weight**: Add `active:'T'` to your query, which would potentially exclude results where active=F, and then use field weights to adjust the impact of this portion of the query: `q.options={fields:['active^0.5']}`. This will require some tuning

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Can you please elaborate last point. Or give some references to be read on

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-compound-queries.html for adding to your query, and see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/weighting-fields.html for more on field weight. I don't want to blindly elaborate in every possible direction you could be confused by but let me know if you have specific questions after you've tried to figure things out (open a new question if appropriate).